# Can't receive data from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

to make it short. 
The app crashes when I want to receive data from the Firebase database.
Here is the code:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
commu = database.getReference("Community");

longi = voteLoni.getText().toString();
lati = voteLati.getText().toString();
final String latiLong = lati + "  -  " + longi;

commu.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Community")
                    .child(latiLong);

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    count= dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue(long.class);
....
```

Structure:
The childs of Community are coordinations

```
DB
  - Community 
    - 89.8 - 90.9
      - count: 4
      - example: 2
      - example2: 4
      - example3: 8
    - 120.9 - 89.9 
      - count: 45
      - example: 24
      - example2: 40
      - example3: 81
```

And that's the error:

```
Process: package, PID: 21441
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
    at app.Activity.Real$2$1.onDataChange(Real.java:122)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:183)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6589)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

But in another activity I'm using the same code `count= dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue(long.class);` - to count the clicks of the user - and it is working...

Thanks in advance

Edit: 
I've added the second child and some values to the database. The `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Community").child(latiLong);`is edited too, but this isn't correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write nested listeners..

If you have this structure:

```
DB
- Community 
  - 1
    - count: 4
```

And you do not have access the the child `1`, then just do the following:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
commu = database.getReference("Community");

commu.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                count= ds.child("count").getValue(Long.class);
               }
           }
 .....
```

This will retrieve the value of `count`

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: hey, I've tried it again. When there is more than one child it isn't working. So this is only working with one child? When I add another it is crashing with the same nullpoint error

Comment: if you have another child, you need to write `childName= ds.child("messages").getValue(Long.class);`

Comment: unfortunately it isn't working for me. Ok I have to say, there are now three more values in it and I want all of them. I've edited the post. Do you have any idea?

Comment: do this `int example = ds.child("example").getValue(Integer.class);`

Comment: Thanks. So with this code there is no error message. But how can I use it outside the for loop? I've declared the int's outside the loop, Sorry not that familiar with programming

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720701/how-to-handle-asynchronous-database-with-firebase